# Move rows based on cell font color

Tags: google-apps-script, colors, google-sheets, triggers

I'm making an automated dispatch workbook, with a total of 5 sheets:
Cooking TBS | Fridge TBS | WFP | PRF | Completed

Calls are entered with specific font colors: if they are 'cooking' the font color black (`#000000`). If they are 'fridge', the font color is blue (`#0000ff`).
 - New calls are entered in the top of the sheets. 
 - Calls with strikeout formatting are moved to completed (work in progress)
 - Calls waiting for info are marked with a '?' and are moved to the PRF sheet
 - Calls waiting on parts are marked with a '-' and are moved to the WFP sheet
 - Return calls that can be scheduled are marked with an "X"

I would like to move cells based on their font color and value, e.g. if the font is 'blue' and the cell value is an 'X', it and related cells should be moved to 'Fridge TBS'.

I am able to move cells based on value alone:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var cookingcolor = '#000000';
  var fridgecolor = '#0000ff';

  if (r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "?") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRFs");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if (r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "-") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WFP");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
```

When I also check the font color, the moves no longer occur:

```
  if (r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "X" && r.getFontColor() == fridgecolor) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("REFRIG TBS");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getFirstRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

  if (r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "X" && r.getFontColor() == cookingcolor) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cooking TBS");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getFirstRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  ...
}
```

[Example workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aN93tKrz3DD1r9ngYGUTRbFn-ZE29Bnka00rzxR1X1Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What's your specific question or issue?

Comment: The script I used for sorting based on color and value isn't working. I'm trying to move rows based on a text color and certain column value - which I'm having an issue with.

Comment: "isn't working" is not a useful description of the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am able to execute the moving of rows with values only. I am having trouble introducing font colors into the script. I am asking for help on a script that will move rows based on the color of the font text - which then I would be able to adapt. Thank you,

Comment: what in your current code does not behave as intended? If you don't provide specifics of the issue, we cannot help. Saying "it doesn't work" is not enough. Have you read the documentation on the methods you use? Logged the values of the colors you want to compare against? What sort of debugging have you done? Are any errors being logged in Stackdriver? (Triggered functions like `onEdit` do not show errors on the UI like manually executed ones do.)

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this. Text in the workbook will have two colors 'black' #000000 and 'blue' #0000ff If a row contains black text I would like it to be moved to a different sheet. I named the colors cookingcolor for black and fridgecolor for blue